# Count distinct words in the row and paste the count in sheet 2

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel column containing multiple sets of data. I want to find the count all the distinct set of records in it and then the result of it to be printed in the Cell of sheet 2 in the same Excel.

> Client
>
> *Burberry Group p
>
> *CA Technologies
>
> *CA Technologies
>
> *CA Technologies
>
> *CA Technologies
>
> *CA Technologies
>
> *CA Technologies
>
> *CA Technologies
>
> CSM Bakery Solut
>
> Deckers Outdoor
>
> Mattel Inc. (Glo
>
> Mattel Inc. (Glo
>
> Mattel Inc. (Glo
>
> Mattel Inc. (Glo
>
> Mattel Inc. (Glo
>
> Mattel Inc. (Glo
>
> Mattel Inc. (Glo
>
> Riverbed Technol
>
> Riverbed Technol
>
> Riverbed Technol
>
> Riverbed Technol
>
> Riverbed Technol
>
> Riverbed Technol
>
> Smurfit Kappa Gr
>
> Smurfit Kappa Gr
>
> Smurfit Kappa Gr
>
> Smurfit Kappa Gr
>
> Thermo Fisher Sc
>
> Thermo Fisher Sc
>
> Thermo Fisher Sc
>
> Thermo Fisher Sc
>
> Thermo Fisher Sc
>
> Thermo Fisher Sc
>
> Thermo Fisher Sc

For the above data.
Result should be 8, as there is 8 client names. But those are repeated in the column.

The result of the count should be printed in sheet 2 cell.

Comment: Where are we on this question, did you receive your answer ?

Answer (score 1):

The following array formula will count unique values in column A on `Sheet1` and then put the result in `A1` on `Sheet2`:

```
Dim s As String
s = "Sheet1!" & Sheet1.Range("A1", Sheet1.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Address
Sheet2.Range("A1") = Evaluate("=SUM(1/COUNTIF(" & s & "," & s & "))")
```

Comment: Wow, that's neat ! do you mind explaining the logic behind that formula ?

Comment: @UriGoren - Sure. It's an array formula. So each cell in the range is processed, in turn, by the formula. The `COUNTIF()` function counts the number of times each value is found. Imagine the name `"Bob"` appears four times in the column. Each time it's found, `COUNTIF()` will return `4`. So each occurrence of `"Bob"` should only count as `1/4`. When you add everything up (`SUM()`), you get `1` unique value. And then `Evaluate()`, of course, allows you to pass a formula as a string and returns the _value_ of the formula back to the cell instead of the formula itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this `VBA` code, assuming your data is in `Sheet1!A2:A100` and the output is in `Sheet2!A1`

```
Dim row As Integer, start_row As Integer, end_row As Integer, v As String, concat As String, count_distinct As Integer
start_row=2
end_row=100
concat="~"
For row = start_row to end_row
  v=Sheet1.Range("A" & row)
  If InStr(concat,v)<=0 Then concat=concat & "~" & v
Next row
count_distinct=UBound(Split(concat,"~"))
Sheet2.Range("A1")=count_distinct
```

The count is in `count_distinct` and the values are in `Split(concat,"~")`

However, You don't need `VBA` to filter out duplicates,

simply read the "Remove duplicate values" section in [Filter for unique values with excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2), it's a built in feature

Comment: This may work for the data above, but imagine `concat` is `~jack~giant` and your next cell contains the word `ant`. Your `InStr()` statement will find it within `giant` and not include it. Also, you're starting with `~` and your first match adds `"~" & v`, giving you `"~~" & v`. You should add `~` _after_ `v` to delimit your entries. Then, change your `InStr()` function to find `"~" & v & "~"` instead of just `v`.